# Enforcing initialization precedence without connectors

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

Is it possible to enforce the precedence of initialization of models in openModelica? For instance assume the following simple model that registers the name and value of each model:

```
function registerModel
  input String name;
  input Real value;
  external "C" registermodel_c(name, value) annotation(Library="registermodelicamodels");
end registerModel

function printRegistered
  external "C" printregistered_c() annotation(Library="registermodelicamodels");
end printRegistered

model a
  parameter Real n;
initial algorithm
  registerModel(getInstanceName(), n);
end a;

model b
  a a1(n=10);
  a a2(n=20);
  a a3(n=30);
end b;

model c
  b b1;
initial algorithm
  printRegistered();
end c;
```

Assume that `printRegistered` prints all the registered `registerModel` queries. Now if model `c` is simulated, `printRegistered` would not print anything. Is there a command to enforce initialization of `b1` inside the `initial algorithm` section of model `c`.

p.s. using connectors might solve the issue (not prefered) but I wonder if there is any other way to tackle this problem.